# Search Data in elastic search through Booking Number

Tags: spring-boot, elasticsearch, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-elasticsearch

Any tell me what is actually problems with my code

i am save data in elastic search related booking
now i want to searching in elastic search thorough booking number. it return wrong data. it show me all record save in elastic search

i want to search like
pass the booking number and return me quick record related to booking number

if(indexType.contains(BOOKING_INDEX) || indexType.contains(ALL_INDEX)) {
matchQueryBuilder = getQueryForAllFields(Booking.class, query, matchQueryBuilder);
matchQueryBuilder = matchQueryBuilder
.should(wildcardQuery("bookingNumber",query))
.should(matchQuery("bookingNumber",query));
indicesList.add(BOOKING_INDEX);
typeList.add("carrierBooking");
}
any help me Out.
Thank In Advance

Answer (score 0):

Rather than a `should` query you can use the `must` or `filter` query. The should query won't filter out the result but increase the score if there are any must or filter queries.

Or you can use [minimum_should_match parameter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html#bool-min-should-match)